# error al escribir con espacios en python

Tags: python

Estoy creando un bot de discord en python y tengo un problema y esque no puedo escribir un comando con espacios...

este es el comando:

```py
@bot.command() 
async def item(ctx, *, nombre,  lang ):
```

imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que intento escribir es:
"!item baba yaga es"
y me da error

aquí dejo el codigo:
a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable, muchas gracias!

```
import json
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help

@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, *, Nombre, lang):
    response = requests.get(f"https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=" +Nombre+ "&searchLanguage=" + lang)
    imagen = response.json()['data'][0]['images']['icon']
    url_imagen = f"{imagen}"
    nombre_local_imagen = "cosmetico.png"
    imagen = requests.get(url_imagen).content
    with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(imagen)
        img2 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 
        img1 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("BurbankBigCondensed-Black.otf", 60)

        draw.text((75, 10), f"IKÓNIKO", font=font, fill="white")  

        img1.paste(img2,(0,0), mask = img2) 
        img1.save("cosmetico.png")
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('cosmetico.png'))
        img1.save("cosmetico.png")
bot.run('')
```

Comment: El error te dice que no le estas pasando un parámetro, que en este caso es `lang`

Comment: En el código que pusiste la función item no tiene ningún argumento lang. Este código es el mismo que el que tienes en el bot? Además otra cosa: podrías darle formato al código? Puedes hacerlo seleccionadolo y presionando las {} arriba de la caja de texto.

Comment: Si, es el mismo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explicación

Tu problema está en que cuando haces que el argumento sea solo por clave, es decir, colocas `, *` antes del argumento, Discord.py interpreta esto como que quieres lo escrito por el usuario luego del comando sin procesar.

Por ejemplo si creo este comando en el bot:

```
@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, nombre, *, lang):
    print("nombre:", nombre)
    print("lang:", lang)
```

Y ejecuto el comando `!item baba yaga    escomando`. Se va a imprimir en consola:

```
nombre: baba
lang: yaga    escomando
```

Como habrás notado, se obtuvo el primer argumento por separado y el resto se guardó en la variable lang sin procesar.

Para discord.py, una función de este tipo:

```
async def item(ctx, *, Nombre, lang):
```

Es como decirle "guardame lo que escribió el usuario luego del comando en la variable nombre". lang es un argumento obligatorio y discord.py no se lo pasa en ningun momento.

#### Solución 1

Haz que la función acepte dos argumentos posicionales. Dejale el trabajo a discord.py de separar cada argumento del comando.

```
async def item(ctx, Nombre, lang)
    # tu código aqui
```

Si el nombre tiene espacios, para que esta forma funcione correctamente, tendrás que pasar primer argumento entre comillas, ya que si no, por ejemplo `!item hola mundo es` será interpretado como 3 argumentos.

El comando que intentas ejecutar debería de quedar así:

```
!item "baba yaga" es
```

#### solucion 2

Procesa lo escrito por el usuario tu mismo. Podemos usar la tecnica del argumento solo de clave para recibir lo que el usuario escribió luego del comando y procesarlo nosotros.
En el siguiente código recibimos los argumentos sin procesar y obtenemos lo que escribió el usuario a cada lado del ultimo grupo de espacios usando [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

```
async def item(ctx, *, args):
    nombre, lang = args.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    # tu codigo aquí
```

El comando tendría que escribirse así: `!item baba yaga es`