# como clonar un usuario bot discord sin que se actualice el nombre anterior con webook y python

Tags: python, discord.py, webhook

Estoy intentando programar un bot en python con webhook, pero tengo un problema

y esque cuándo escribo el segundo nombre del usuario el nombre de arriba se actualiza, y no se deberia de actualizar

A esto me refiero

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxvzYeIibwE

Pero en cambio este bot webhook no lo hace:

https://i.imgur.com/WI6o7n2.gif

(No me deja añadir la imagen .gif)

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='URL WEBHOOK', content='hola que tal',username="nombre del usuario",avatar_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/4.png")

response = webhook.execute()
```

No se como hacerlo, alguien me podria ayudar?, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de realizar el proceso, creando la webhook usando `discord.py`:

**Paso 1:** Accede al canal donde quieres que se envíe la respuesta.

**Paso 2:** Crea una `webhook` para el canal con la función [`create_webhook()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=textchannel#discord.TextChannel.create_webhook). El nombre que le des a la `webhook` no es importante ya que la vas a borrar en el paso 5:

```
webhook : discord.Webhook = await channel.create_webhook(name='haboo')
```

**Paso 3:** Customiza el nombre y la imagen que tendrá la `webhook`. Como ejemplo, voy a usar como nombre e imagen las del usuario al que se está respondiendo:

```
username = message.author.nick if message.author.nick else message.author.name
avatar_url = message.author.avatar.url
```

**Paso 4:** Envía un mensaje a través de la `webhook` con la función [`Webhook.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=textchannel#discord.Webhook.send), indicando el contenido del mensaje así como el nombre y la imagen elegidas:

```
await webhook.send('Contenido de mensaje', username=username, avatar_url=avatar_url)
```

**Paso 5:** Borra la webhook. Es importante ya que es una herramienta que permite enviar mensajes a un canal sin autorización. Además, el número de `webhooks` activas para un mismo servidor son limitadas, es una buena práctica borrarla siempre después de utilizarla:

```
await webhook.delete()
```

---

Adjunto un ejemplo de código completo usando el evento `on_message()`. Cuándo se envía un mensaje que contenga la subcadena "prueba", el bot envía un mensaje con contenido "Mensaje" con el nombre y la imagen del usuario original a través de una `webhook`. Finalmente, el bot borra el mensaje original.

Modificar el código para que funcione con un comando es sencillo:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message : discord.Message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    
    if 'prueba' in message.content.lower():
        await send_message_from_webhook(message)
        await message.delete()

async def send_message_from_webhook(message : discord.Message):
    webhook : discord.Webhook = await message.channel.create_webhook(name='haboo')
    username = message.author.nick if message.author.nick else message.author.name
    avatar_url = message.author.avatar.url

    await webhook.send("Mensaje", username=username, avatar_url=avatar_url)
    await webhook.delete()
```

---

Nota: Para poder crear o eliminar webhooks, tu bot debe tener el permiso `manage_webhooks` habilitado en el servidor:

[image: Cómo activar el permiso]

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, pero ahora tengo un problema y esque cuando añado mi codigo para generar cada habbo(Personaje) me tira error en consola

él código que tengo: https://i.imgur.com/zDvzzSX.png

y el error: https://i.imgur.com/9nPZR9O.png

Comment: @Juan el problema está en la cabecera de la función `send_message_from_webhook()`. La función pide más parámetros de los que le estás  proporcionando cuando la llamas desde el evento `on_message()`. Modifica la cabecera de la función o pásale los parámetros necesarios cuando la llamas

Comment: La solución más sencilla sería, ya que al parecer tu "keko" y "mensaje" son variables que no tienen que ver con el mensaje enviado por el usuario, calcularlas dentro de la función `send_message_from_webhook()`, es decir, deja la cabecera como en el ejemplo y ya en el cuerpo haz `keko = ...` y `mensaje = ...`. Si me equivoco y sí tienen que ver con los datos del objecto `discord.Message`, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/486236/306873) tienes una respuesta que te puede ayudar.